# What is the youtube Zend gdata api rate limit?

Tags: youtube-api, gdata-api

I am using **Youtube Zend GDATA API**, I want to know the exact limit of the API calls i make to Youtube. And also tell me what is the procedure they follow if limit is exceed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't say direct numbers, only that a quota limit exists. However, I believe your app has to have a huge amount of usage to exceed the limits.

See more [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#quota).